# select dynamic element using document doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).on('ul li:nth-child(even)',function(){
    $(this).addClass('e');
});
```

user can add and delete `li`, but with the code above it doesn't seem work.

Comment: You must specify the event type. Look at `on` documentation.

Comment: I used like this  $('ul li:nth-child(even)').addClass('even'); it doesn;t work too

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. Can you precise what you try to do ?

Comment: add class to every 2nd item of my li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) here; on is designed for event attaching and handling:

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events
>   to the selected elements.

Try:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(even)').addClass('e');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6u6wS/